# Error occurs in one project, not in a partially replicated second project. Related to playing multimedia

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6.1

I have two projects. In them I am trying to play video with either AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayerController.

In the one large project that I've been developing in for a few months, I've added a new screen, a button, and code to display the video. Pressing the button displays the video. It did not work; the video displays a "loading..." for a second and then the application breaks, showing me the main method - highlighting this line:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppAppDelegate class]));
```

In the second project which I've just created, I mimic the new screen, button, and code exactly that I just tried adding to the first project. This project displays the video perfectly.
The first project fails with either AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayerController, the second works fine with either.

I've made the new screen in the first project the initial view controller, with the same failing result.

I'm not sure what information to show you. The debug console? The frameworks I have included in one but not the other?

I'm at wits end trying to figure this out, the slightest suggestion would mean a lot.

Comment: Have you tried having a breakpoint set on all exceptions? Run the profiler?

Comment: Yes I have a breakpoint set on all exceptions. You've just taught me something new regarding the profiler; is there a specific one i should use (leaks, activity monitor, etc)?

Comment: Ran the profiler for allocations/leaks. It worked. The video shows fine. But it doesn't outside the profiler. That seems rather strange..

Comment: Oh my god you're a genius. Thanks. How that's managed to not happen someplace else in the last 5 months I will never know. If you want the credit for solving it throw this in an answer and I'll select it.

Comment: I removed the comment and I added as answer. (Don't know if is the right way to do it :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by application breaks, it's crashing or it's just paused ?. I had a similar problem on one of my project and the problem was caused by the breakpoint set on all exceptions, it seems that the MPMoviePlayerController throws some exceptions while playing the movie but they are handled properly but the breakpoints stop the app in some strage places

Comment: Sorry that took so long, it slipped my mind going in to the weekend (and I think I wanted to forget that I wasted 7 hours of my life on a breakpoint). Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, I know that feeling, it happend to me that's why I knew the issue.